# Generator Functions: Conditionally yield result of another generator

Tags: javascript, generator

There was a question here recently (which I can't find) that had a die roll problem that posed an interesting condition:

Roll three die, and generate a color value that represented their position of each entity rolling a die (in order to provide a `background-color`).  `green` for "winner", `yellow` for 2nd place, `red` for 3rd place and `blue` for draw.

[**EDIT**]: Initially I created a Class with a generator function like this, where the inner generator terminated after the first time it was used (thanks @Pointy)

```
    class Event {
      ...
      
      * generateColor() {
        let color = this.single.next() // potential discard
        while (this.result > 1) {
          yield "blue"
        }
        yield color.value
      }
```

Current iteration looks like this.

```js
class Event {
  constructor(description) {
    if (description) {
      console.log(description)
      this.description = description
    }
    this.result = null
    this.generator = this.generateColor()
  }

  * singleColor() {
    yield "green"
    yield "yellow"
    yield "red"
  }
  
  * generateColor() {
    while (this.result > 1) {
      yield "blue"
    }
    yield* this.singleColor()
  }
  
  getColor(result) {
    this.result = result
    return this.generator.next()
  }
}

let event = new Event('three different rolls')
console.log(event.getColor(1))
console.log(event.getColor(1))
console.log(event.getColor(1))

event = new Event('one high roll, two draws')
console.log(event.getColor(1))
console.log(event.getColor(2))

event = new Event('two draws, one low roll')
console.log(event.getColor(2))
console.log(event.getColor(1))

event = new Event('three draws')
console.log(event.getColor(3))
```

The expected results are:

green, yellow, red
green, blue
blue, *yellow*
blue

However results being generated are:

green, yellow, red
green, yellow
blue, *green*
blue

How can this be corrected?

Comment: Seems like `getColor()` should probably be re-initializing the single color generator.

Comment: @Pointy if the single color generator was reinitialized it would always yield green

Comment: Quite convoluted. I think the best option by far would be to not use generators here.

Comment: @CertainPerformance sure, it's pretty trivial logically, but the point was to experiment with generators, not solve a logic problem

Comment: Your `generateColor()` function only calls `.next()` once, when it is first evaluated, on the "single" generator. Thus it will never get a new value.

Comment: @Pointy this seems to be correct, yeah.  Thanks.  Just need to figure out if there is a way around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to consume any way the `singleColor()` values, but have them overruled by "blue" when the result property is greater than 1.

In your implementation however:

- your code is not generating those `singleColor()` values until the result property has been set to one. No progress is made in that iterator while "blue" is being yielded, so that "blue" is not *replacing* any color from `singleColor()`. It merely is a *prelude* series of "blue" before the complete `singleColor()` sequence is started.
- Once the `singleColor()` iteration starts, the value of the result property no longer has an influence on this -- no more "blue" is produced.

To change that behaviour, make sure you iterate the `singleColor()` colors from the start, and then check in each iteration the result property to decide whether *that* value or its "blue" replacement is yielded.

Implementation:

```js
class Event {
  constructor(description) {
    if (description) {
      console.log(description);
      this.description = description;
    }
    this.result = null;
    this.generator = this.generateColor();
  }

  * singleColor() {
    yield "green";
    yield "yellow";
    yield "red";
  }

  * generateColor() {
    while (true) {
      for (let color of this.singleColor()) {
        yield this.result > 1 ? "blue" : color;
      }
    }
  }

  getColor(result) {
    this.result = result;
    return this.generator.next().value;
  }
}

let event = new Event('three different rolls')
console.log(event.getColor(1))
console.log(event.getColor(1))
console.log(event.getColor(1))

event = new Event('one high roll, two draws')
console.log(event.getColor(1))
console.log(event.getColor(2))

event = new Event('two draws, one low roll')
console.log(event.getColor(2))
console.log(event.getColor(1))

event = new Event('three draws')
console.log(event.getColor(3))
```